# Integrate a loop in a python script

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner in Python and would really appreciate if someone could help me with the following:
I would like to run this script 10 times and for that change for every run the sub-batch (from 0-9):

E.g. the first run would be:

```
python $GWAS_TOOLS/gwas_summary_imputation.py \
-by_region_file $DATA/eur_ld.bed.gz \
-gwas_file $OUTPUT/harmonized_gwas/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE.txt.gz \
-parquet_genotype $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/chr1.variants.parquet \
-parquet_genotype_metadata $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/variant_metadata.parquet \
-window 100000 \
-parsimony 7 \
-chromosome 1 \
-regularization 0.1 \
-frequency_filter 0.01 \
-sub_batches 10 \
-sub_batch 0 \
--standardise_dosages \
-output $OUTPUT/summary_imputation_1000G/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE_chr1_sb0_reg0.1_ff0.01_by_region.txt.gz
```

The second run would be

```
python $GWAS_TOOLS/gwas_summary_imputation.py \
-by_region_file $DATA/eur_ld.bed.gz \
-gwas_file $OUTPUT/harmonized_gwas/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE.txt.gz \
-parquet_genotype $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/chr1.variants.parquet \
-parquet_genotype_metadata $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/variant_metadata.parquet \
-window 100000 \
-parsimony 7 \
-chromosome 1 \
-regularization 0.1 \
-frequency_filter 0.01 \
-sub_batches 10 \
-sub_batch 1 \
--standardise_dosages \
-output $OUTPUT/summary_imputation_1000G/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE_chr1_sb0_reg0.1_ff0.01_by_region.txt.gz
```

I am sure this can be done with a loop but not quite sure how to do it in python?

Thank you so much for any advice,
Sally

Comment: Do you want to (a) modify `gwas_summary_imputation.py` so that it can process all the sub-batches in a loop, (b) run `gwas_summary_imputation.py` from some newly to be created Python script, or (c) just get the job done even if it's not in Python? For (c) I can offer you the `for` loop in the bash shell: `for ((sub_batch=0; sub_batch<10; sub_batch++)); do python ... -sub_batch $sub_batch ...; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for seems to be a way to run the same command on the command line a set number of times.

If you're on Linux using the bash shell, this can be done using a shell loop:

```
for i in {0..9}; do
python $GWAS_TOOLS/gwas_summary_imputation.py \
-by_region_file $DATA/eur_ld.bed.gz \
-gwas_file $OUTPUT/harmonized_gwas/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE.txt.gz \
-parquet_genotype $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/chr1.variants.parquet \
-parquet_genotype_metadata $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/variant_metadata.parquet \
-window 100000 \
-parsimony 7 \
-chromosome 1 \
-regularization 0.1 \
-frequency_filter 0.01 \
-sub_batches 10 \
-sub_batch $i \
--standardise_dosages \
-output $OUTPUT/summary_imputation_1000G/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE_chr1_sb0_reg0.1_ff0.01_by_region.txt.gz
done
```

If you're on Windows, similar can be achieved using powershell:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 9; $i++) {

    python $GWAS_TOOLS/gwas_summary_imputation.py \
    -by_region_file $DATA/eur_ld.bed.gz \
    -gwas_file $OUTPUT/harmonized_gwas/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE.txt.gz \
    -parquet_genotype $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/chr1.variants.parquet \
    -parquet_genotype_metadata $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/variant_metadata.parquet \
    -window 100000 \
    -parsimony 7 \
    -chromosome 1 \
    -regularization 0.1 \
    -frequency_filter 0.01 \
    -sub_batches 10 \
    -sub_batch $i \
    --standardise_dosages \
    -output $OUTPUT/summary_imputation_1000G/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE_chr1_sb0_reg0.1_ff0.01_by_region.txt.gz
}
```

Comment: I work on linux. So I would just do a gwas.sh file and paste everything above in and run the job via qsub?

Comment: Don't get in to the habit of copying and pasting code without understanding what it's doing. I would build it up, start with the loop to echo $i once your happy it's working as intended, you could put it into a script. I can't help you with the qsub scheduler as I'm not running it here

Comment: Thanks, I do understand what is going on, I just wasnt sure how to do it in this case. I understand that i will be replaced by 0-9 and once reached 9 it will end.

Answer (score 1):

While we can't show you how to retrofit a loop to the python code without actually seeing the python code, you could just use a shell loop to accomplish what you want without touching the python code.
For bash shell, it would look like this:

```
for sub_batch in {0..9}; do \
  python $GWAS_TOOLS/gwas_summary_imputation.py \
  -by_region_file $DATA/eur_ld.bed.gz \
  -gwas_file $OUTPUT/harmonized_gwas/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE.txt.gz \
  -parquet_genotype $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/chr1.variants.parquet \
  -parquet_genotype_metadata 
  $DATA/reference_panel_1000G/variant_metadata.parquet \
  -window 100000 \
  -parsimony 7 \
  -chromosome 1 \
  -regularization 0.1 \
  -frequency_filter 0.01 \
  -sub_batches 10 \
  -sub_batch $sub_batch \
  --standardise_dosages \
  -output $OUTPUT/summary_imputation_1000G/CARDIoGRAM_C4D_CAD_ADDITIVE_chr1_sb0_reg0.1_ff0.01_by_region.txt.gz 
done
```

Comment: ahhhh that is very good, i didnt think about that. thank you so much, i will try it now!!

Answer (score -1):

a loop in python from 0 to 10 is very easy.

```py
for i in range(0, 10):
    do stuff
```

Comment: Answer below due to limited space in comment section.

Comment: And what would the `do stuff` look like if it's an external Python script?